# Visual studio 2008 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In VS2008 I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut for "Get Latest Version (recursively" and "Rebuild Solution".

I go to tools-->options-->environment-->keyboard

found "File.GetLatestVersion", "File.GetLatestSolutionFiles" and "Build.RebuildSolution".

I chose "use new shortcut in" to be Global/VisualStudio, but in both cases no shortcut I assign (and is accepted. I can see it later on listed as a shortcut) responds when I try to click it when I'm working.

What am I doing wrong? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 7):

Well in VS2005 with a C++ project, and VS2008 with a C# project assigning a shortcut worked for me.

Steps:

1. open tools -> options -> environment - > keyboard
2. in 'show commands ..' enter 'build.r'
3. select 'Build.RebuildSolution'
4. in 'Press shortcut keys:' press Ctrl+M, Ctrl+B
5. press 'Assign'
6. The combo appears in the "Shortcuts for selected command:" combo as global
7. press 'Ok'

then press combo, and watch solution rebuild.

For both versions, having the current file in focused as a non-project did not affect the shortcut, as I thought it might.